# Unable to load HTML templates from subdirectories with Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm having n issue with loading html files with go gin framework 
when i loaded the entire templates folder from the main function its not reading the subdirectories and only read files . 
package app

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    router = gin.Default()
)

func StartApp() {
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*/*.html")
    routersMap()
    router.Run(":8080")

}
```

based on the project structure it supposed to show the Loaded HTML Templates as

```
[GIN-debug] Loaded HTML Templates (2): 
    - layouts/default.html
    - layouts/index.html
    - pages/index.html
```

but actually the output showing this result

```
[GIN-debug] Loaded HTML Templates (3):
        - default.html
        - index.html
        -
```

it doesn't even showing the second index.html file 
Project Structure 
[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 3):

I am also working on learning go and using gin.

I came across this issue also and ran into a few minor issues that i resolved.
I will leave this here in case it may someone else.

Folder layout:

```
.
├── controllers
│   ├── controller.go
│   └── gui.go
├── html
│   └── templates
│       ├── homepage
│       │   └── index.html
│       ├── layouts
│       │   ├── footer.html
│       │   ├── header.html
│       │   └── menu.html
│       └── views
│           └── library.html
├── models
│   ├── bookstruct.go
│   └── dbconnection.go
├── server.go
└── test
    └── server_test.go
```

The part that is probably needed are these files:

- server.go
- gui.go
- library.html

**gui.go**

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
...

// BooksView display book library
func BooksView(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(
        http.StatusOK,
        "views/library.html",
        gin.H{"title": "Books"},
    )
}
```

**library.html**

```
{{ define "views/library.html" }}
<!--Embed the header.html template at this location-->
{{ template "layouts/header.html" .}}

<h1>Hello Books!</h1>

<div>Est nisi debitis recusandae necessitatibus voluptate ut. Laudantium eligendi nostrum quisquam voluptates harum
    exercitationem nam harum. Voluptatem sit assumenda sit alias dolores. Modi autem et temporibus impedit qui numquam.
    Esse ut recusandae quos deserunt nihil repellendus. Sint et voluptatem quia quia dolor aut.</div>

<div>Est nisi debitis recusandae necessitatibus voluptate ut. Laudantium eligendi nostrum quisquam voluptates harum
    exercitationem nam harum. Voluptatem sit assumenda sit alias dolores. Modi autem et temporibus impedit qui numquam.
    Esse ut recusandae quos deserunt nihil repellendus. Sint et voluptatem quia quia dolor aut.</div>

<!--Embed the footer.html template at this location-->
{{ template "layouts/footer.html" .}}
{{ end }}
```

**server.go**

```
import (
    c "go_first_api/sub_packages/gormrestapi/controllers"
    m "go_first_api/sub_packages/gormrestapi/models"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

// RunServer will run and create a server using gin
func RunServer() {
    ...
    r := gin.Default()
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("sub_packages/gormrestapi/html/templates/**/*")
    r.GET("/library", c.BooksView)
    ...

    r.Run(":8088")
}
```

***NOTE:** main.go is above this sub-dir in the folder path.*

Answer (score 0):

See [gin#html-rendering](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#html-rendering),
Using templates with same name in different directories `templates/**/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem by reading all files from templates directory recursively ([link](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/464)):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "path/filepath"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    
    // load templates recursively
    files, err := loadTemplates("templates")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    router.LoadHTMLFiles(files...)
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(
            http.StatusOK,
            "index.html",
            gin.H{
                "title": "Home Page",
            },
        )
    })

    err = router.Run("localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Http server crashed: " + err.Error())
    }
}

func loadTemplates(root string) (files []string, err error) {
    err = filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fileInfo, err := os.Stat(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if fileInfo.IsDir() {
            if (path != root) {
                loadTemplates(path)
            }
        } else {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return err
    })
    return files, err
}
```